# Using a function from each object in a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, iterator

Im coding an enigma machine and having trouble using elements in my vector, getting only a segmentation fault as an error. I need to use a function from each of the rotors in my vector on a single character, transforming the character as the iterator moves along, once forwards through the list, once backwards. I have commented out other transformations to isolate the problem.

Machine.cpp

```
#include "Machine.h"

using namespace std;

Machine::Machine(const vector<Rotor>& rots, const Plugboard & pb)
    : rotors(rots), plugboard(pb) {}

// give c's alphabet index
int Machine::getPosition(char c) {
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        return c - 'A';
    } else {
        cout << "not an accepted character";
        return -1;
    }
}

// give letter at index i in alphabet
char Machine::atPosition(int i) {
    assert(i >= 0 && i <= 25);
    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" [i];
}

char Machine::encode(char c) {
    assert(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
    // plugboard
    // c = plugboard.getMatch(c);
    // forward pass through rotors
    for (std::vector<Rotor>::iterator it = rotors.begin(); it != rotors.end(); ++it) {
        c = it->process(c);
    }
    // reflector
    // c = Reflector::reflect(c);
    // backwards pass through rotors
    for (std::vector<Rotor>::iterator it = rotors.end(); it != rotors.begin(); --it) {
        c = it->processInverse(c);
    }
    return c;

}
```

the relevant call part of my main function:

```
  Rotor rot1(argv[1]);
  Plugboard pb1(argv[2]);
  vector<Rotor> rotors(1, rot1);
  Machine machine(rotors, pb1);
  machine.encode('A');
```

Comment: Just a tip for debugging: you should definitely try using a memory debugger when programming in c++. I would personally recommend drmemory. It has saved me countless hours of frustration when trying to solve seg faults and memory leaks.

Comment: _"getting only a segmentation fault as an error"_ Time to fire up your debugger! Then you'll get a _lot_ more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're iterating backwards incorrectly. The iterator pointed to by `rotors.end()` is one past the end of the vector, it's not a valid object... so calling a function on it is undefined behavior.

If you want to iterate backwards, you have to use the reverse iterators:

```
for (std::vector<Rotor>::reverse_iterator it = rotors.rbegin();
    it != rotors.rend(); ++it) {
    c = it->processInverse(c);
}
```

Comment: That's correct. It would also be possible to use the non-reverse iterators, but in that case, the decrement would need be be at the beginning of the body instead of the third position in the for loop (or at the end of the body, which is equivalent).

Comment: @MichaelKarcher The decrement is fine where it is, you just have to change the bounds to go from `std::next(rotors.end(), -1)` to `std::next(rotors.begin(), -1)`. But that's a lot more confusing.

Comment: @Barry: `std::next(rotors.begin(), -1)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That makes sense. Well, even more reason not to do it with forward iterators :)

Comment: @Barry So Bernjamin established that you can not shift the bounds, but of course, you could replace `it->processInverse(c)` by `std::next(it, -1)->processInverse(c)` to be able to keep the decrement where it is. But I agree that using reverse iterators solve all the common pitfalls of reverse operating loops over containers.